# Segmentation Fault on C++ Server Linux Machines - Works on Mac

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, memory

I'm working on this *HOMEWORK* assignment and have spent quite a bit of time on it at this point. I've been able to get my Mac to run both the client and Server flawlessly but the requirements say it must run on a Linux machine, which is where I have found my major issue with it. I'm receiving a segmentation fault right after the client connects to the server, and it is happening between two cout lines which makes no sense to me. I've spent about 4 hours looking into this at this point of time with no luck. Would anyone be able to give me any helpful pointers? Thanks in advance!

Server.cpp

```
//header files

//input - output declarations included in all C programs
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

//contains definitions of a number of data types used in system calls
#include <sys/types.h>

//definitions of structures needed for sockets
#include <sys/socket.h>

//in.h contains constants and structures needed for internet domain addresses
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace std;

int* clientNumbers  = new int[50];

void initializeArray()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        clientNumbers[i] = 0;
    }
}

//This function is called when a system call fails. It displays a message about the error on stderr and then aborts the program.
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
int numberClients = 0;
bool checkNumber(int number)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if(number == clientNumbers[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    clientNumbers[numberClients] = number;
    numberClients++;
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    pid_t childPID;

    initializeArray();

    //sockfd and newsockfd are file descriptors,These two variables store the values returned by the socket system call and the accept system call.
    //portno stores the port number on which the server accepts connections.
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;

    //clilen stores the size of the address of the client. This is required for the accept system call.
    socklen_t clilen;

    //serv_addr will contain the address of the server, and cli_addr will contain the address of the client which connects to the server.
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    //create socket
    //it take three arguments - address domain, type of socket, protocol (zero allows the OS to choose thye appropriate protocols based on type of socket)
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    string portNumber;
    cout << "Please Enter Port Number:";
    getline(cin, portNumber);


    //stoi() function can be used to convert port number from a string of digits to an integer, if your input is in the form of a string.
    try{
        portno = stoi(portNumber);
    }catch(const std::invalid_argument e)
    {
        error("ERROR No Port Number Entered.");
    }


    if(portno > 65535 || portno < 1)
    {
        error("Invalid Port Number. Exiting.");
    }

    //contains a code for the address family
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //contains the IP address of the host
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    //contain the port number
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    //bind() system call binds a socket to an address, in this case the address of the current host and port number on which the server will run.
    //three arguments, the socket file descriptor, the address to which is bound, and the size of the address to which it is bound.
    if (::bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

    //listen system call allows the process to listen on the socket for connections.
    //The first argument is the socket file descriptor, and second is number of connections that can be waiting while the process is handling a particular connection.
    listen(sockfd,5);

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "Server waiting...\n";

        //This is where the program experiences a Segmentation Fault

        cout << "Just Before Clilen";
        clilen = (socklen_t) sizeof(cli_addr);

        //accept() system call causes the process to block until a client connects to the server.
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                            (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                            &clilen);

        cout << "WE MADE IT THIS FAR!";

        if (newsockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR on accept");

        string clientNumberString;
        int clientNumber = 0;
        n = read(newsockfd,&clientNumberString,15);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket\n");
        clientNumber = stoi(clientNumberString);

        if(checkNumber(clientNumber)) {

            //reads from the socket into a buffer for a maximum of 255 characters
            //read call uses new file descriptor, the one returned by accept()

            if(fork() == 0)
            {
                cout << "Established Connection With: " << clientNumber << "\n";
                while(1)
                {
                    string lowerCase;
                    //Read in String from Client
                    n = read(newsockfd, &lowerCase, 255);
                    if(n == 0)break;

                    //transform(lowerCase.begin(), lowerCase.end(), lowerCase.begin(), ::toupper);

                    string upperCase = "";

                    for(int i = 0; i < lowerCase.length(); i++)
                    {
                        upperCase += toupper(lowerCase.at(i));
                    }

                    n = write(newsockfd, &upperCase, upperCase.length() + 1);
                }
                cout << "Disconnecting from Client\n";
                //close connections using file descriptors
                close(newsockfd);
            }

        }else
        {
            n = write(newsockfd, 0, 1);
            cout << "CONNECTION REFUSED: Client Number already Taken.\n";
            break;
        }

    }

        //
        close(sockfd);


    return 0;
}
```

Running output example:

```
 ./server
 Please Enter Port Number:6666
 Server waiting...
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Backtrace from GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (
    nptr=0x2388058 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2388058>, 
    endptr=0x7fffffffde00, base=10, group=<optimized out>, 
    loc=0x7ffff78ba060 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
298 ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace

#0  __GI_____strtol_l_internal (
    nptr=0x2388058 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2388058>, 
    endptr=0x7fffffffde00, base=10, group=<optimized out>, 
    loc=0x7ffff78ba060 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:298
#1  0x0000000000401ca1 in __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int, char, int> (
    __convf=0x401350 <strtol@plt>, __name=0x401da9 "stoi", 
    __str=0x2388058 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2388058>, 
    __idx=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/string_conversions.h:62
#2  0x0000000000401bab in std::stoi (__str=..., __idx=0x0, __base=10)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2825
#3  0x00000000004017fd in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfe8) at main.cpp:143
```

Comment: Where is the backtrace from gdb?

Comment: Because the output is not being flushed, you don'r actually know where it crashed. "Just Before Clilen"; is very likely sitting in the output buffer waiting to be written to the console when the seg fault occurs. "WE MADE IT THIS FAR!" Could also be in the buffer. No way to tell if debugging by screen dumps. Slapping a `<<std::endl` on the end of the debug outputs is probably the easiest way to improve the odds seeing these messages.

Comment: I have added the gdb backtrace. Thank you for the tip on the endl,  I will make those adjustments. I'm new to c++!

Comment: Global variables, manual dynamic memory and magic numbers are a recipe for disaster. Use `int clientNumbers[50] = {};` to create an array of 50 0s. Or better yet use a class to represent your used clients, and a vector which can grow as needed, and `std::find` to do this search

Comment: `if(fork() == 0)` spawning a duplicate process to handle a client connection doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: I'd guess you're corrupting the internal structure of your string here:  `n = read(newsockfd,&clientNumberString,15);`  You need to resize the string before you try and read into its buffer.

Comment: Trace says the fault occurs with a call to stoi  on line 143. This it: `clientNumber = stoi(clientNumberString);` ? If so, better mane sure n is not zero after the call to read.

Comment: @RetiredNinja has it. You can't just write into a string like that. For one thing, there's more than just the char array in a string, so treating it like one is going to end badly.

Comment: Thought about it a bit more and I'm pretty sure you want to replace the fork with a thread or something. Fork will duplicate the process that called fork. That means you now have two servers running, both listening on the same port. I've never tried it, so I don't know how that's going to turn out. I need to brush up on my POSIX-fu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for something that can segfault, consider the function CheckNumber.

If there is any chance the test is exceeding the count of 50, it will segfault. This is because at the end of the function there is no test to ensure the numberClients is kept in range.

Further, unless you've written overloads for read and write, your calls aren't going to work. Consider"

std::string s;

read( sock, &s, 10 );

This should give warnings in better compilers, but will not work. s is not going to operate as a string class when passed in as a void * this way.

You will have to provide a character array, perhaps:

char s[ 12 ];

read( sock, s, 10 );

Then, you can move that buffer into a std::string if you want to use the string class from there forward.

Comment: You probably won't get an error message on screwing up read's buf parameter because it's a `void *`. So long as you give a `void *` a pointer it's happy. One of the reasons to shy away from them.

Answer (score 4):

```
    string clientNumberString;
    int clientNumber = 0;
    n = read(newsockfd,&clientNumberString,15);
```

You trash your string here by reading data on top of it. A `string` is not just an array of characters, it's a structure that contains a pointer, a length, and possibly other information. You can't just write arbitrary data at its address and expect that to work.

Also, it seems that you have some fundamental misunderstandings about how TCP works:

```
    n = read(newsockfd,&clientNumberString,15);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket\n");
    clientNumber = stoi(clientNumberString);
```

After the first line, `n`, and only `n` holds the number of bytes you received. So how is `stoi` supposed to know how many bytes to look at? Also, say the number is "12" but the `read` only read the "1" because the "2" hadn't been sent yet. You'll get the wrong number. This seems to suggest that you fundamentally don't understand the TCP is a stream of bytes.